# Probability of dice game. If I lose it is your turn

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, dice

Lets play a game.
We are two players and one dice.
I will toss first. If I get a 1, I win. If not, it is your turn.
You toss it, you win if you will get a 2. If not, it is my turn again.
We continue until someone wins.

What is the probability for me to win?

Comment: The probability you win on your $n$'th turn is $(\frac{5}{6})^{2n-2}\frac{1}{6}$  (*seen by direct application of multiplication principle, for you to win on the $n$'th turn, you miss, then I miss, repeated $n-1$ times, then you get your desired number*).  Since $n$ can range over all possible natural numbers greater than or equal to $1$ and there is no overlap between cases, the total probability you win is...

Comment: Relevant wiki post: [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Notice that the actual numbers for each player are irrelevant. If you do not win on the first throw the game is exactly the same for the other player as it was for you at the start. So?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursively,

$$p =\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)p$$

hence

$$p = \frac{6}{11}$$

Explanation: You win either right away, or else, if you get a chance to roll again, you're back to the initial state.

Alternatively, using Martin Rattigan's hint,

$$p =\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)(1-p)$$

which also yields

$$p = \frac{6}{11}$$

Explanation: You win either right away, or else, regarding the second player as the starting player in a new game, you want that player to lose.